# Как создать модальное окно на React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Получил задание нарисовать модальное окно на React Native.
После изучения документации и примеров , так и не удаётся показать на экране окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше, верстая, на html и css всё было проще и понятнее.
Здесь же всё иначе.

Может имеется хороший пример модального окна (и верстки фона) у вас? (CodePen, Jiddle?)

Comment: кажется что-то есть в доках по этому поводу

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal